# How to include/extend Jinja2 template string variable in another variable

Tags: python, django, jinja2

Trying to make the code DRYer by nesting templates like this:

```
base = Template('''
  - alert:
     cluster: {{cluster}}
     role: {{role}}
     slack: {{slack}}
''')

alert = Template('''
    {% include base %}
     description: Critical {{role}} system load
     threshold: xxx-yyy-zzz
''')

print alert.render(cluster='cluster1', slack='alerts', role='database')
```

The above does not work, getting the exception:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 989, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 754, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "<template>", line 2, in top-level template code
TypeError: no loader for this environment specified
```

Please advise.

Comment: Hint: The issue is because of `{% include base %}`

Comment: Got it, the question how to make include work..

Answer (score 1):

You are merely not passing the reference to `base` when rendering `alert` template.

```
>>> print alert.render(cluster='cluster1', slack='alerts', role='database', base=base)
################                         just pass this reference of `base` ^

  - alert:
     cluster: cluster1
     role: database
     slack: alerts
     description: Critical database system load
     threshold: xxx-yyy-zzz
```